# Salgar ciclovias?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Aqui na Holanda, quando neva, como agora no Inverno, eles colocam sal sobre as ciclovias. Julgava que o verbo ***salgar*** poder-se-ia aplicar a este contexto, mas o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/salgar) assim define este verbo:

> 1. Temperar com sal (ex.: já temperei e salguei o peixe). ≠ DESSALAR, DESSALGAR
> 2. Pôr demasiado sal (ex.: acho que salguei o arroz). ≠ DESSALAR, DESSALGAR
> 3. Pôr sal sobre carnes cruas ou outros alimentos, para os conservar. = ENSALMOURAR, SALMOURAR
> 4. [Antigo]  Espalhar sal em terreno onde se cometeu crime de profanação, para que fique estéril.
> 5. [Ocultismo]  Fazer feitiço, espalhando sal à porta de alguém.
> 6. Tornar mais intenso ou mais engraçado (ex.: ele gosta de salgar as conversas).
> 7. [Informal]  Fazer subir o preço ou o valor de algo (ex.: a seca vai salgar a conta da água; salgar os preços).

Afinal, pode ou não pode o estado holandês *salgar* as ciclovias?

Comment: Eu não usaria **Salgar** nesse contexto. No meu entender, **Salgar** dá o sentido de alterar o sabor (mesmo de uma conversa). Mesmo que no caso do "Crime" se usa salgar.

Comment: Se os países de língua portuguesa tivessem grandes nevadas no inverno, certamente esse uso já estaria bem estabelecido.  Concordo com Stafusa: se podemos salgar o solo como forma de maldizê-lo, porque não podemos salgar estradas, ciclovias, etc ?  A verdade é que não temos necessidade de fazê-lo.  Se tivéssemos, esse uso já estaria estabelecido nos dicionários.

Comment: @Centaurus, em Bragança, Portugal, neva com frequência.

Comment: @Aónio   Varia muito, Aônio.  Em 2007-2008 foram apenas 5 dias com nevadas em Bragança.  Em 2008-2009 foram 21 dias com nevadas.  Mas nunca o suficiente para atingir 30-40 cm em um único dia, como em Toronto ou Boston.  Eu me referi a "grandes nevadas".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que sim.

Se "salgar" pode ser usado para o ato de espalhar sal sobre solo profanado, por que não sobre solo com neve?

Comment: *Impregnar* é genérico, mas tu terias alguma dificuldade em impregnar uma estrada asfaltada com sal; e o sal que por ventura se impregnasse não teria o efeito desejado. Claramente esse "impregnar" é para carne, peixe, coisas com capacidade de absorção do sal. Parece-me perfeitamente aceitável dizer "salgar estradas" num contexto em que se compreenda o que se quer dizer. É uma extensão simples do significado comum de *salgar*. Mas eu defenderia isso nestes termos, não com base na Infopédia. Ela só te serviu porque explica pior que o Priberam.

Comment: @Jacinto De acordo, removi a referência.

Answer (score 3):

Essa noção de *salgar* não vem nos dicionários nem é de uso corrente. Vi também na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/salgar), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/salgar/), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/salgar), dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001) e Dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), e nada. Existe uma edição mais recente do Houaiss; não sei se virá lá.

Agora, os dicionários não determinam novos usos: primeiro começa o pessoal a usar uma palavra nova, ou uma antiga num novo sentido, e só depois é que os dicionários, com maior ou menor atraso, registam o novo uso.

Já se tem usado *salgar* nesse teu sentido, mas muito infrequentemente. Procurei no Google, e encontrei apenas uma meia-dúzia de exemplos (negrito meu): “**salgar as estradas** no inverno” neste manual de [*Princípios de Geologia* (Porto Alegre, 2013)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4Q8oNHt-_mkC&pg=PA716&lpg=PA716&dq=%22salgar%20as%20estradas%22&source=bl&ots=3M0DjMeSP4&sig=ACfU3U36pMxpgI3FzgMytnWLhCn5MTbPfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ1JrhlYfgAhUny4UKHdIdAFkQ6AEwCnoECA4QAQ#v=onepage&q=%22salgar%20as%20estradas%22&f=false), “equipamento de remoção de neve e de **salgar as ruas**” [(artigo online de 2010)](https://carteirosempoeta.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/parem-tudo-vai-nevar/) mais uns dois ou três do mesmo género. Há mais uns tantos exemplos, mas parecem ser traduções automáticas; pelo menos são globalmente de má qualidade. Portanto não se pode dizer que esta aceção de *salgar* seja de uso corrente.

Pronto, estes são os factos que eu consegui apurar. Agora a minha opinião, para o que ela possa servir, é que é perfeitamente razoável usar *salgar* nesse sentido em contextos em que fique claro o que se quer dizer, como por exemplo nesta [*Apostilha Eletroquímica*](https://www.ebah.com.br/content/ABAAAAjKwAJ/apostila-eletroquimica?part=7) (num bog, fórum, ou coisa parecida):

> Nos países de clima frio, a melhor forma de retirar uma camada de gelo de um caminho do jardim, é salpicando uma pequena quantidade de sal comum no gelo. Para **“salgar” as estradas**, as autoridades utilizam substâncias mais baratas que o NaCl […]

O autor optou aqui por escrever *salgar* entre aspas, para indicar está a tomar liberdades com a linguagem. Esta noção de *salgar* é uma simples extensão do significado comum da palavra, e o interlocutor compreenderá perfeitamente. As aceções 4 e 5 do Priberam—salgar a terra para a tornar estéril ou a soleira da porta para enfeitiçar—mostram que este tipo de extensões do significado comum da palavra são facilmente entendíveis.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que se deve utilizar antes 'aplicação de sal na via'  e não 'salgar a via' visto que o sal afecta a formação de gelo e não a via em si.